# Replacement of HTTParty.send with Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty, faraday

I am rails beginner working on a task to replace HTTParty with Faraday. So in codebase I call put/post/get based on the verb like so:

`response = HTTParty.send(verb, url, http_options)`

I am aware that Faraday provides an option to call them individually like so:
`Faraday.put(url) do |req|`

Can I somehow abstract it, to call based on the verb.

Please let me know, if I can answer any questions.

Comment: Any reason why `Faraday.send(verb, url, http_options)` doesn't work for you? [Faraday usage](https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/) seems to suggest this would be entirely acceptable. Maybe you are confused as to how this is working in `HTTParty`? In this case it is doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Awesome! much thanks. ```Faraday.send(verb, url, http_options)``` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thats actually just `Object#send` which all objects in Ruby respond to. `"dlrow olleH".send(:reverse)`